# How to alert the front end user if a button is clicked but an input field was given no value jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

I'm very new to jquery. I have a game and I've been trying to build.

I asked in a previously question how to execute appending a result value based off a dynamically created input and button element. I was able to succesfully append a result alerting the user based off the input field.

However now I would like to alert the user to keep trying if the user doesn't enter any input, but still clicks the button.

Heres my code..

```js
$('#guessCheck').on('click', function () {
    //
    // chose the right inputs
    //
    $(this).prop('disabled', true);
    let highestRating = $('#checkedImageContainer input[type=number]').map(function () {
        return {ele: $(this), val: parseFloat(this.value)};
    }).get().sort(function (a, b) {
        return b.val - a.val;
    })[0].ele;
    $('#third-rule').removeClass('hidden');
    $('#guessImageContainer').removeClass('hidden');
    console.log('removed hidden class on the #highestrated list');
    $('#guessImageContainer').append('<li><img id="favoriteImage" src="' + highestRating.prev('img').attr('src') + '" name="' + highestRating.prev('img').attr('name') + '"><input id="guessMyValue" type="text"><button class="text-center" id="finishButton">Finish Button</button><h2 class="text-center">Now Guess The Name Of Your Favorite Image</h2></li>');
    registerFinishButtonListener();
});

function registerFinishButtonListener() {
    $('#finishButton').on('click', function () {
        console.log("finish button clicked");
        let userGuessInput = $('#guessMyValue').val();
        $('#fourth-rule').removeClass('hidden');
        $('#resultContainer').removeClass('hidden');
        //Disable user from clicking the button again
        $(this).prop('disabled', true);
        //If the user guesses right\/\/\/
        if (userGuessInput === $('#favoriteImage').attr('name')) {

            $('#resultText').append("You GUESSED RIGHT!!<br> IMAGE = " +
                    $('#favoriteImage').attr('name'))
        }
        //If the user guesses wrong\/\/\/
        else if (userGuessInput != $('#favoriteImage').attr('name')) {

            $('#resultText').append("Unfortunately your WRONG!!!<br> Imgae =" + $('#favoriteImage').attr('name'))
        }
        //IF THE USER GIVES NO VALUE\/\/\/
        else if (userGuessInput.val() === 0) {
            //Re enable the button from being clicked because the user still 
            // needs to give the inpuyt field a value
            $(this).prop('disabled', false);
            alert("Make sure you give it your best shot!!LMAO")
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: you should compare with empty string "" not 0

Comment: userGuessInput.val() === "" ???

Comment: `userGuessInput` is already the `value`, so you did `$('#guessMyValue').val().val()`. You also compared against `0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add the logic that handles the user guessing with no value before any of the other logic happens, and then use a return statement to prevent the code from continuing to execute, like so:

```
function registerFinishButtonListener() {
$('#finishButton').on('click', function (){
  console.log("finish button clicked");
  let userGuessInput = $('#guessMyValue').val();
  $('#fourth-rule').removeClass('hidden');
  $('#resultContainer').removeClass('hidden');
  //Disable user from clicking the button again
  $(this).prop('disabled', true);
  //If the user guesses right\/\/\/

  //IF THE USER GIVES NO VALUE\/\/\/
   if (userGuessInput.val().length === 0){
    //Re enable the button from being clicked because the user still 
  needs to give the inpuyt field a value
    $(this).prop('disabled', false);
    alert("Make sure you give it your best shot!!LMAO")
    return;
  }

  else if (userGuessInput === $('#favoriteImage').attr('name')){

      $('#resultText').append("You GUESSED RIGHT!!<br> IMAGE = " + 
  $('#favoriteImage').attr('name') )
  }
  //If the user guesses wrong\/\/\/
  else if (userGuessInput != $('#favoriteImage').attr('name')){

      $('#resultText').append("Unfortunately your WRONG!!!<br> Imgae = 
  " + $('#favoriteImage').attr('name'))
  }

 });
```

Also, your logic to evaluate if the string was empty was incorrect.  I believe  you were trying to look at the length of the string, in order to do so you need to access the length property of the given string like this:

```
userGuessInput.val().length
```

Comment: @Max Happy to help :)

Comment: and does this work this way just because the coding thinks to loop from top to bottom, so if that expression is on the bottom the computer just never reaches it?

Comment: Correct.  Although I wouldn't say "looping" is the right term, but yes, the execution path will never quite reach that block of logic at the bottom because the other conditions are being evaluated to true first.